# Multi-class classification in R

Tags: r, twitter, multilabel-classification

I have tweets of a particular account, I want to go through each tweet and categorize into class labels like business, music, sports etc.

My approach for creating training data is to assign few keywords to each class label, for example

1. Keywords for “Business” could be - entrepreneur, job, GDP…
2. Keywords for “Music” could be - songs, genre, album…

.CSV file for training data has 2 columns 
1. Keywords
2. class

Is this the right way to go ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are trying to do is similar to a dictionary method. It's pretty straightforward to apply a dictionary to a corpus of texts, but given that you are using tweets I'd recommend using Kenneth Bennoits excellent [Quanteda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/index.html) package.

More specifically you can create a custom dictionary (an s3 class I believe) from a list of terms.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/quanteda.pdf

and then apply the dictionary using applyDictionary.  You'll get back a nice table with the text and the dictionary keys, like the following:

```
docs    christmas opposition taxglob taxregex country
  text1         1          1       1        0       0
  text2         0          0       1        0       2
```

Comment: I tried it out, this was the exact thing I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.  Quanteda is definitely a great text analysis tool. Also good because it understands twitter!

Comment: It is a silly thing to ask, but I'm not able to find solution to this. I have stored "sport", "carry" in my dictionary but whenever I encounter words related to them like "sports", "carries", its not able to identify them. Any suggestion how to go about it?

Comment: You can try adding the endings to your dictionary. You could also use wordstem(), part of quanteda, and then rebuild your dictionary using the stemmed versions of your words.